# wlo1 Interrupt:19

Tags: boot, networking, wireless, ifconfig, interrupts

I have got a problem with my network. After I installed bunch libs and Programms (i am sure that none of them is about the network) to my ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS, I am no longer able to connect to wifi. When I ran ifcongfig, it shows me "Interrupt:19" at the end of "wlo1" which should be my wifi-card. Can someone help me to fix this? And I am still in a learning phase of Linux, so it would really help me out if you can tell me what are the commands about. Thank you very very much!

Comment: Nothing is wrong with `Interrupt:19`. Can you post the full output of `ifconfig` TO YOUR QUESTION?

Comment: Ok, if that s not wrong, I probably should get a new wifi-card, everything else should be fine. Thank you a lot!